# How to get command line arguments in Spring Boot that excludes spaces?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am using Intellij and passing multiple arguments in the Edit Configuration, with this format:
`--name=Naruto --information=Ninja` and it works but the problem comes if I try to use a List of String as an input but I don't know how to pass that in the args. I do `--fields=Type,Interest,Fighting Style`
Now, it only reads up to Fighting and skips the later characters.
I need it with the space because I am turning these fields into a csv file and I don't want it as FightingStyle. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried enclosing Strings with quote marks? Like `--fields=Type,Interest,"Fighting Style"`?

Comment: @JettoMartínez oh yes it worked. Also works with "Type,Interest,Fighting Style". Thank you so much, I have another question here if you don't mind. I'm catching these args with List<String> fieldNames = args.getOptionValues("fields"); 
I thought this would make it a list of strings with 0 = Type, 1 = Interest, etc but that is not the case, any idea why?

Comment: The implementation of the method `getOptionValues(String arg)` works that way. [According to the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationArguments.html#getOptionValues-java.lang.String-), you need one argument per key, such as `--fields=Type --fields=Interest --fields="Fighting Style"`. I will post an answer with this (in case it works) and your original question, so please consider accepting it as the solution to help others with your same question in the future.

Comment: @JettoMartínez answer accepted! this was my first time asking a question here. Really a great community, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose that part of the String with quote marks, like:

`--fields=Type,Interest,"Fighting Style"`